# Generating HTML from server-side block in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a very newbie kind of ASP.NET question: I simply don't know and can't work out the correct syntax to use.

In my view I want to generate an action link if a certain condition is true on my model.  I know how to generate a link using this syntax:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "DoSomething", new { id = Model.ID }) %>
```

But for some reason that syntax doesn't work in this code:

```
<%
  if (Model.CanDoSomething)
    Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "DoSomething", new { id = Model.ID });
%>
```

I **really** am a newbie to ASP.NET, so I don't even know what the semantic name is for the different syntaxes `<%` and `<%:`; all I can tell is that `<%` is to `void` as `<%:` is to `string`.  And clearly executing a line of code that just returns a string (`Html.ActionLink()`) is not going to have any effect.  But what, pray **what** is the correct method to make my page render the action link?

It's a great pity I can't Google on "<%"!  Any links or explanations of this subject will also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
<% if (Model.CanDoSomething) { %>
   <%: Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "DoSomething", new { id = Model.ID }) %>
<% } %>
```

`<%:` writes to the output buffer but encodes the string. You could also use `<%=` for unencoded output because `ActionLink` returns an encoded `MvcHtmlString`.

**EDIT:** This may also work

```
<%
  if (Model.CanDoSomething)
    Response.Write(Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "DoSomething", new { id = Model.ID }));
%>
```

Comment: Sure it would, and I worked that out myself.  But surely there's a more elegant way of handling this kind of situation?

Comment: @Shaul. Yes. Using Razor view engine instead. :)

Comment: You can switch to MVC 3 with Razor view engine. This one has a far more intuitive syntax.

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit with Response.Write.  That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<% - this by itself has no output. You would include code with no output in this block such as an if statement. If you want output - you must use it in conjunction with <%=
The difference with the : is that
<%:  means it will output to the response stream, not = required however the : means the output will be htmlencoded.

```
<%:"sometest&text" %>   //will emit "sometesttext" on the page.. htmlencoded.
<%="sometest&text" %> //will give you the same result without the '&' htmlencoded
<% SomeFunction() %> //will just run that function - there is no output
//you want
<%if (Model.CanDoSomething){%>
    <%:Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "DoSomething", new { id = Model.ID })%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, if not exactly the solution I was looking for - thanks!

Comment: thanks : ) how did it differ? Personally - I wouldn't use the Response.Write syntax. Its going to be a tad more work if you refactor going to razor syntax. There is also no need to use the htmlencoding colon syntax there either, since <%: HtmlEncodes, and the ActionLink helper already spits out type MvcHtmlString which says 'don't encode me'